# why is this directive not working ..can someone explain?

Tags: angularjs

This is my html page:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scoping_directives.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="scoping">
        <div ng-controller="OuterController">
            <p>{{outer_var}}</p>
            <my-directive></my-directive>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the JS file :

```
angular.module('scoping', [])
    .controller('OuterController', function($scope){
      $scope.outer_var = 10;

    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
      console.log("inside directive1");
      return {
        /*scope :{
            inner_var : 20
        },*/
        template:'<p>tanmay</p>'
      };
    });
```

can someone please explain why the template in the directive is not rendered. I am only getting  10 as the output . There is no error as such produced by the output.

Comment: Directives by default are restricted to attributes. See the $compile documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: and you are using your directive as an element. In other words restrict: 'E' is needed

Comment: On the link I found this :

String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. If omitted, the defaults (elements and attributes) are used.

E - Element name (default): <my-directive></my-directive>
A - Attribute (default): <div my-directive="exp"></div>
C - Class: <div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>
M - Comment: <!-- directive: my-directive exp -->

Comment: Its not clear what is the default value, it say for both 'E' and 'A'

Comment: @Sacho This is true for angular < 1.3. Since [1.3.0-beta.17](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta17-turing-autocompletion-2014-07-25), the default value is `restrict: 'EA'` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[restrict](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)** option is typically needed in directive which should be set to:

**'A'** - only matches attribute name
**'E'** - only matches element name
**'C'** - only matches class name

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

**'AEC'** - matches either attribute or element or class name

The detail description is shown below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/goxm8p7f/)**

```
angular.module('scoping', [])
    .controller('OuterController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.outer_var = 10;

})
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    console.log("inside directive1");

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p>tanmay</p>',
        replace: true
        /*scope :{
            inner_var : 20
        },*/
    };
});
```

With the restrict property of a directive's definition object we can decide where our directive can appear in the DOM. We have four options:

**1. Element**

```
restrict: 'E'
```

The directive can appear only as HTML element.

Example:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

**2. Attribute**

```
restrict: 'A'
```

The directive can appear only as HTML attribute in an element. This is the default value if restrict is not specified.

Example:

```
<div my-directive="expression"></div>
```

**3. Class**

```
restrict: 'C'
```

The directive can appear only inside a class attribute of a HTML element.

Example:

```
<div class="my-directive: expression;"></div>
```

**4. Comment**

```
restrict: 'M'
```

The directive can appear only inside a HTML comment.

Example:

```
<!-- directive: my-directive expression -->
```

Courtesy of **[angularjshub - restrict](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/restrict/)**

Comment: Yes, this works but I have seen cases and examples where restrict was never specified and still it was working. Check out thishttps://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: check out this :https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
Here we have examples where restrict attribute is never specified and also it says "Note: When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute and elements only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by class name, you need to use the restrict option."